# Storing and Printing User Data in Flask as an Array

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm currently working on a Flask application, and I have a requirement to store the details entered by the user and print them as an array within the Flask application. Here's an overview of what I'm trying to achieve:

Users enter various details on a web form, including name, prn, email, branch, and phone number.

I want to capture these details for each user and store them in an array.

After capturing the details, I would like to print the user data as an array within my Flask application.

This would allow me to keep a record of all the user details submitted through the application.

I have made some progress with my code, but I'm encountering challenges in properly storing and printing the user data as an array. Here's a simplified version of my code:

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, jsonify
from twilio.base.exceptions import TwilioRestException
from twilio.rest import Client
from flask_session import Session
import random
import time  # Import the time module

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your secret key'
app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
ACCOUNT_SID = "AC1cc730c1ff114811e81366da054f5141"
AUTH_TOKEN = "760e1008b26d1f5365f90bac0e54d18f"
TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER = "+19726959384"
twilio_client = Client(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)
Session(app)

def generate_otp():
    return ''.join(random.choice('0123456789') for i in range(6))

def send_otp(twilio_client, phone_number, otp):
    try:
        message = twilio_client.messages.create(
            body=f'Your OTP is: {otp}',
            from_=TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
            to=phone_number
        )
        return message
    except TwilioRestException as e:
        return None

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/getOTP', methods=['POST'])
def get_otp():
    if 'phone-number' in request.form:
        phone_number = str(request.form['phone-number'])
        otp = generate_otp()
        message = send_otp(twilio_client, phone_number, otp)

        if message:
            session['otp_code'] = otp
            # Store the time when the OTP was generated
            session['otp_time'] = time.time()
            return jsonify({"message_sid": message.sid, "status": "OTP sent"})
        else:
            return jsonify({"error": "Failed to send OTP"})
    return jsonify({"error": "Phone number is required"})

@app.route('/verifyOTP', methods=['POST'])
def verify_otp():
    if 'verification-code' in request.form:
        code = request.form['verification-code']
        if code == session.get('otp_code'):
            # Check if the OTP is still valid (generated within the last 60 seconds)
            otp_time = session.get('otp_time', 0)
            current_time = time.time()
            if current_time - otp_time <= 60:

                return jsonify({"status": "success"})
            else:
                return jsonify({"error": "OTP has expired"})
        return jsonify({"error": "You entered the wrong code!"})
    return jsonify({"error": "Verification code is required"})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
HTML:


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie.edge">
    <title>OTP Verification Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        let code;
        let phoneSent = false;

        function sendPhoneNumber(number) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/getOTP',
                data: { "phone-number": number },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if (data.status) {
                        alert(data.status);
                    } else {
                        code = data.code;
                        let element = document.getElementById("hidden");
                        element.classList.remove("hidden");
                        element.classList.add("visible");
                        phoneSent = true;
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }

        function verification() {
            let phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone_number_field').value;
            if (phoneNumber === "") {
                alert("You need to input a phone number!");
                return false;
            }

            if (!phoneSent) {
                console.log(phoneNumber);
                sendPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            }
        }

        function verifyotp() {
            let userCode = document.getElementById('otp_code_field').value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/verifyOTP',
                data: { "verification-code": userCode },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status) {
                        let status = data.status;
                        switch (status) {
                            case "success":
                                console.log("Code is right!");
                                let form = document.getElementById('verification-form');
                                form.classList.add('display__none');
                                let message = document.getElementById('message');
                                message.innerHTML = "Success!";
                                message.classList.remove('display__none');
                                break;
                            default:
                                alert("An error occurred: " + status);
                                break;
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");
                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="verification-form">
                <h1 style="color: #ff73b3;">OTP Verification Demo</h1>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" id="info" />
                <input type="number" name="prn" placeholder="Enter PRN" id="info" />
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email" id="info" />
                <input type="text" name="branch" placeholder="Enter your branch" id="info" />
                <input type="text" name="phone-number" placeholder="Input phone number" id="phone_number_field" />                
                <input type="text" name="verification-code" placeholder="Input verification code" id="otp_code_field" />
                <button onclick="verification()">Submit</button>
                <button onclick="verifyotp()">Verify OTP</button>

            </div>
            <h1 id="message" class="display__none">Code is successful</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The user_data_list is meant to store the user data, but I'm unsure if I'm handling it correctly.

If anyone has experience with Flask and can guide me on how to efficiently capture user data and print it as an array within the Flask application, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.